# Why does a `DateTime?` DisplayTemplate render empty text for DisplayForModel()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, nullable

I have some code in my view to display a nullable DateTime:

```
@if (this.Model.DateOfBirth.HasValue)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
}
else
{
    @: None
}
```

I plan to use this same thing in several places, so I created a very simple DisplayTemplate. The result:

Code in view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "DateOrNone")
```

Code in \Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\DateOrNone.cshtml

```
@model DateTime?

@if (this.Model.HasValue)
{
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
}
else
{
    @: None
}
```

This works perfectly if the property is null, but nothing is rendered if it has a non-null value. I also tried changing `Html.DisplayForModel()` to `Html.DisplayFor(m => m)` or `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Value)`, with the same results.

I've also attempted to explicitly set the DisplayTemplate to use in DateOrNone like so:  `@Html.DisplayForModel("Date")` or (after explicitly creating a "Test" template with the text "Testing") @Html.DisplayForModel("Test")`. I've attempted various permutations of these tests. The date is always rendered as empty.

I specifically need the DateOrNone DisplayTemplate to call `DisplayFor/DisplayForModel` so that the DateOfBirth is displayed using the proper DisplayTemplate. I could take the code from the DateTime DisplayTemplate and copy it into the DateOrNone file, but that kind of defies the point of making the code DRY.

Any suggestions on getting the date to render properly?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you created a display template named `DateTime.cshtml`, correct? Well, that is what `DisplayFor`/`DisplayForModel` will use, so when you're calling those within the display template itself, you're essentially causing an endless loop of rendering the same template. I've never tried something like this before, but presumably, Razor just throws it's hands up and returns nothing, instead of erroring out on you.

Your display template should actually define what should be displayed, so what you should be doing is something like:

```
@model DateTime?

@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    @(string.Format(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString ?? "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}", Model.Value))
}
else
{
    @:None
}
```

Rather than calling `Html.DisplayForModel`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While this isn't the situation, I realize that my question needs to be more explicit about some of the details. I've edited the question with additional information

Comment: See update above. If your only issue is you want it to follow what's set via the `DisplayFormat` attribute, then you can use the model metadata to retrieve that and use it as your format string. If it's not set, it'll be null, so I'm coalescing with a default format string here.

Comment: Are you implying that using DisplayFor is simply not an option?

Comment: From my limited testing, it appears not. I was able to recreate the same problem you encountered. Using `Display*` when already inside a display template returns nothing

Comment: Thank you for recreating the issue. I was hoping that I was just doing something wrong. We currently have several DisplayTemplates for complex types that use `DisplayFor`. It must be a limitation of templates for "simple types". If so, that is surprising and unfortunate.

Comment: Yes, it's limited to scalar types. However, I don't see how it's "unfortunate". You can still easily achieve what you want via the tools that you're given.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to format `DateTime`, try

```
@model DateTime?
@Model.ToLongDateString()
```

Comment: That code absolutely works, but it doesn't do what I need it to do. Everything is rendered correctly when the code is directly in the view. Once it is moved to the custom template it won't render the date. I specifically need to use "DisplayFor". In the end the date will be rendered by an additional DisplayTemplate.